# .htaccess rewrite everything to index.php except scripts in a specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two publicly accessible folders:

```
/public
/legacy
```

Now I want redirect all requests to /public/index.php except those that start with /legacy:

```
/users --> /public/index.php
/legacy/somescript.php --> /legacy/somescript.php
```

currently I only have the following .htaccess files:

/:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

/public and /legacy:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(legacy/.*)$
RewriteRule . /public/index.php [L]
```